# Common lisp idiom - is there a better way?

Tags: common-lisp

I find myself doing this sort of thing all the time.  I've been considering writing a macro/function to make this sort of thing easier, but it occurs to me that I'm probably reinventing the wheel.

Is there an existing function that will let me accomplish this same sort of thing more succinctly?

```
(defun remove-low-words (word-list)   
  "Return a list with words of insufficient score removed."
  (let ((result nil))
    (dolist (word word-list)  
      (when (good-enough-score-p word) (push word result)))                                      
    result))
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are several built-in ways of doing this. One way would be:

```
(remove-if-not 'good-enough-score-p word-list)
```

And another:

```
(loop for word in word-list  
      when (good-enough-score-p word)
      collect word)
```

And yet another:

```
(mapcan (lambda (word)
          (when (good-enough-score-p word)
            (list word)))
        word-list)
```

Etc... There's also [SERIES](http://series.sourceforge.net/) and [Iterate](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/). The Iterate version is identical to the LOOP version, but the SERIES version is interesting:

```
(collect (choose-if 'good-enough-score-p (scan word-list))))
```

So, yes, you're very likely to reinvent *some* wheel. :-)

Comment: Thank you -- I've never really come up with a reason to use mapcan before, but this shows me the way.  For this particular example, remove-if / remove-if-not is better, but still, very nice.

Answer (score 6):

The function you want is `remove-if-not`, which is built-in.

```
(defun remove-low-words (word-list)
  (remove-if-not #'good-enough-score-p word-list))
```

If you feel like you are re-inventing something to do with lists, you probably are. Check the Hyperspec to see.

- [The Hyperspec documentation on `remove-if-not`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm#remove-if-not)
- [All sequence functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_sequen.htm)
- [All list-specific functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_conses.htm)

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple ways you can do this.  First, and probably most easily, you can do it recursively.

```
(defun remove-low-words (word-list)
  (if (good-enough-score-p (car word-list))
      (list word (remove-low-words (cdr word-list)))
      (remove-low-words (cdr word-list))))
```

You could also do it with `mapcar` and `reduce`, where the former can construct you a list with failing elements replaced by `nil` and the latter can be used to filter out the `nil`.

Either would be a good candidate for a "filter" macro or function that takes a list and returns the list filtered by some predicate.

Comment: I believe your version has no base case, among other problems.